# How to extract some part of the path in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a variable with path `/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1`. How can I extract `/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp` in shell script?

Comment: What are the rules? cut at Nth `/` ? A regex?

Comment: I just want to remove the ```/folder1/folder``` at the end.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: In a comment here you say you just want to delete the "`/folder1/folder`" bit of the directory path, but in the [another comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768369/how-to-extract-some-part-of-the-path-in-shell-script/768571#comment1466636_768371), you say that this part is variable. Would it be fair to say that you want to delete _the last two_ parts of the directory path, or is the number of trailing directories also variable? If so, is the number of directory parts at _the start_ of the directory path fixed?

Answer (score 6):

Using shell *parameter expansion*:

```
dir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1
echo "${dir%/*/*}"
```

```
/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp
```

---

*Parameter Expansion* expands parameters: `$foo`, `$1`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}"`, `"${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted.

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and
`LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`
Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: In this, ```/folder1/folder1``` varies each time. Can you please provide an alternative?

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Might be worth noting that while`${var%pattern}` is a standard sh operator (initially from ksh), `${files[@]: -4}` is non-standard (from ksh93, though now also found in bash and zsh). However it will expand to the last 4 elements of the array here, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In the zsh shell, for:

> `dir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1`
> to
> `newdir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp`

If it's about removing 2 path components off the end:

```
newdir=$dir:h:h
```

Same as in csh¹, that takes the `h`ead of the `h`ead of the path using the `:h` history [modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) here applied to parameter expansion.

If it's about getting the first 9 components of the path:

```
newdir=${dir:h9}
```

If it's about getting everything up to the left-most occurrence of `/_tmp`:

```
newdir=${(M)dir#*/_tmp}
```

For the right-most occurrence:

```
newdir=${(M)dir##*/_tmp}
```

`${var#pattern}` and `${var##pattern}` are operators from the Korn shell to expand to the value of `$var` stripped of the shortest and longest string respectively at the start matching `pattern`. With the `M` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), instead of removing it, it expands to the part that is `M`atched.

---

<sup>¹ The behaviour differs from `csh` though with `dir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1/` or `dir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1//` where zsh gives you the same result while csh considers those trailing `/`s as additional path components like the `${dir%/*/*}` of ksh would.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `dirname`:

```
dir=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1
dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$dir")"

/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have no newline (\n) in your path variable then this can be done with sed:

```
$ A=/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp/folder1/folder1
$ cutoff=/folder1/folder
$ echo "$A" | sed "s#$cutoff##"
/usr/apps/app1/home/usera/run/10/_tmp1
```

(As your strings include forward slash you need to use a different delimiter in sed. Choose a delimiter that doesn't exist in cutoff variable)

Comment: There are issues here: 1) You don't quote `$A` with `echo`, so any globbing pattern will be used by the shell to find matching filenames, and they could be removed if e.g. `nullglob` was enabled (in `bash`). 2) The delimiters used with the `s` command in `sed` would, if they occurred in `$cutoff`, cause issues. 3) File paths can _technically_ contain newlines on Unix, which means that a line-oriented tool like `sed` would need to take extra care to be able handle generic pathnames. 4) `echo` can, depending on the configuration of the shell, replace things like `\n` etc. with other characters.

Comment: In short, you must specify that your answer assumes that no filepath contains newlines, the character `#`, a number of different `\X` escapes, that the shell is not set up to do filename globbing, that `$cutoff` matches at the correct place by ensuring it's a valid regular expression and that special characters, like `[` and backslash are escaped, etc.